# Silverstripe _config.php is not being loaded locally

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a Silverstripe site that is running fine on the production server. However, when I try to run it locally,I get this error message - "SilverStripe Framework requires a $databaseConfig defined."

I have noticed that my local _config.php doesn't get loaded. I have checked file permissions. But still no clues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20384423/612253

Comment: Does your mysite/_config.php contain a line like `require_once('conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php');` ? Then you have a _ss_environment.php on your server, either in webroot or a folder above, where the database credentials are in.

Comment: @wmk I know. That file is loading but my config is not loading at all.

Comment: can you paste your config file? and the _ss_environment.php? maybe obfuscate the passwords...

Comment: Is your `$databaseConfig` in your `_config.php` file or in the `_ss_environment.php` file? Have you tried running a `?flush=1` as config files, like many other PHP files for SilverStripe, are cached.